# createdBy and lastModifiedBy fields missing in drive search results in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm sending a search request to the `/me/drive/root/search` endpoint. I'm specifying which fields to return using the `$select` query parameter as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='sdflkdshflkjhsdf')?$select=webUrl,name,lastModifiedDateTime,createdBy,lastModifiedBy,createdDateTime,folder,image,id
```

However the drive item objects returned are missing some of the fields I requested. For example here is the response to the above query:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='sdflkdshflkjhsdf')?$select=webUrl%2cname%2clastModifiedDateTime%2ccreatedBy%2clastModifiedBy%2ccreatedDateTime%2cfolder%2cimage%2cid&$skiptoken=s!MTtlMDIzYmJlYi03NmUwLTRmMGUtYTljMy02MmE0MTNiM2RlZDE",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-08-03T12:59:28Z",
            "id": "01ZGVHW2FL7NNJJOD5AVGIMHTNV2BTATLB",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-08-03T12:59:28Z",
            "name": "sdflkdshflkjhsdf.pdf",
            "webUrl": "https://[REDACTED].sharepoint.com/personal/oscar_[REDACTED]/Documents/sdflkdshflkjhsdf.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the `createdBy` and `lastModifiedBy` fields have not been returned. Are these fields not supported on this endpoint? The documentation says the endpoint returns full DriveItem objects which should include these fields.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue in Graph Explorer. This is the query I tried: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?$select=webUrl,name,lastModifiedDateTime,createdBy,lastModifiedBy,createdDateTime,folder,image,id&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

Comment: Strange. I cannot get those fields to come down with the exact same query (except for the search term) on my instance. However when I fetch the DriveItem directly with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01ZGVHW2FL7NNJJOD5AVGIMHTNV2BTATLB the createdBy and lastModifiedBy fields are present.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. In documentation is said, that

[Drive Recent](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Drive Item search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that both should return the same object [DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

When I tried to search

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='MY_RECENT_DOC.docx')?$top=1`

gave me response without `createdBy` or `lastModifiedBy`.

But when i used 'recent API', the same object with the all information was presented.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?$top=1`

Like @oscar-robinson said you can use `id` (what is always visible) and this id you can use to another search where all information will be presented.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}`